# Alterar browser padrão do PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, google-chrome, pgadmin

Hoje ao abrir o `PgAdmin4`, ele abre por padrão no `Edge` da minha máquina. É possível alterar isso para o `chrome`? Ao tentar somente copiar o link e colar, isso não funciona.

> Unauthorized
>   The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Instalei o `pgAdmin4` juntamente com o pacote que o próprio `postgresql` oferece, versão `10.11`.

Comment: Seria isto https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905092/1518921 ?

Comment: Poderia ser... Mas ele está abrindo uma nova janela do próprio `pgAdmin4`, porém não abre em guia do `chrome`

Comment: Ele não abre mais no `edge`, mas também não abre como aba do `chrome`

Comment: Agora sim, abriu na aba do `chrome`, obrigado Guilherme

Comment: Formulei como resposta. Apaguei os comentários antigos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mudar o navegador clique o direito do mouse/rato no icone do pgAdmin que fica no systemTry:

> [image: pgadmin em systemtry]

Seleciona <kbd>Configure...</kbd> e então no campo <kbd>Browser Command</kbd>:

> [image: pgadmin com browser customizado]

Coloque o caminho do seu browser seguido de `%URL%`, exemplo:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %URL%
```

Se for o Firefox seria algo semelhante a isto:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %URL%
```

Se deseja abrir o Chrome como um "app standalone" para o pgAdmin use com o argumento `--app` (somente suportado pelo chrome, até aonde sei):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app %URL%
```